# In IBS SPSS how can I output open ended feedback grouped by demographics

Tags: spss

I am working on a project in IBM SPSS 25. I have a series of responses where users were invited to provide open ended responses to questions. I would like to organize and output them based on answers to demographic questions.

For example:
QID99_1 is the open ended question.
QID3 is a Demographic question

I would like to organize QID99_1 by QID3

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
report  format=list /variables= QID99_1 /break= QID3.
```

You can look up report command to play around with [format](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/spss-statistics/29.0.0?topic=report-format-subcommand-command) options.